# How to check the http request in unit testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to write an unit test for my app. It contains http request call in my case.

Test file

```
'use strict';
describe('Controller: testCtrl', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var testCtrl, scope, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, $cookies) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
        });
    }));

    it("should return product data", function() {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/store/' + productID + '/products').respond([{
            //not sure what I should do next...
        }])
    })
```

controller file

```
  $http.get(('/api/store/' + productID + '/products').success(
            function(data) {
             //the data could contain 10 objects with 10+ property within each object.
            }
        );
```

Since the http request return a very complex object, I am not sure how to write my test. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You assume that your API works correctly, and what you're trying to actually test is:

- does your app respond to the URL it should?
- does it do any processing of th data it should?

So return a mock object in your whenGET, with enough detail for any data processing code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the test goes, you will have to return a mock object response. That being said, you do not need to pollute your test case with your 1000 line mock JSON. Simply save it in a separate file and use [karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-ng-json2js-preprocessor) to return it from the `whenGET`.